# Merge data from one column with another column then remove the unneeded column

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array and I want to merge its two field value in one field.
need
**link = link + footnote**

```
  Array
    (
        [title] => CBS Blocks Time
        [link] => http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/02/cbs-blocks-time-warner-cable-subscribers-from-watching-full-episodes-on-cbs-com/
        [pubDate] => Fri, 02 Aug 2013 00:00:00 +0000
        [dc_creator] => Ryan Lawler
        [dc_language] => en
        [dc_format] => text/html
        [footnote] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://www.twcableuntangled.com/2013/08/twc-removes-cbs-programming/
                [1] => https://twitter.com/CBS
                [2] => https://twitter.com/TWC
                [3] => http://CBS.com
                [4] => https://twitter.com/TWC
                [5] => http://twitter.com/#!/brianstelter/status/363435685249687552
                [6] => http://www.techmeme.com/101016/p12#a101016p12
            )
    )
```

**Need Output**

```
Array
(
    [title] => CBS Blocks Time
    [link] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/02/cbs-blocks-time-warner-cable-subscribers-from-watching-full-episodes-on-cbs-com/
            [1] => http://www.twcableuntangled.com/2013/08/twc-removes-cbs-programming/
            [2] => https://twitter.com/CBS
            [3] => https://twitter.com/TWC
            [4] => http://CBS.com
            [5] => https://twitter.com/TWC
            [6] => http://twitter.com/#!/brianstelter/status/363435685249687552
            [7] => http://www.techmeme.com/101016/p12#a101016p12
        )
    [pubDate] => Fri, 02 Aug 2013 00:00:00 +0000
    [dc_creator] => Ryan Lawler
    [dc_language] => en
    [dc_format] => text/html
)
```

This is my approach

```
    $result = array();
foreach($item as $val){
    foreach($item['footnote'] as $val1){
        $result['link'] = $val1;
    }
}
pr($result);
```

Comment: So what have you tried, or are you just hoping that somebody will do the work for you

Comment: Posting your attempts usually help.

Comment: It's a pretty trivial 2 lines of code to do what you want, so show your code and we might be able to explain why it's not working and how to fix it; but SO is not a free coding service

Comment: @MarkBaker I have pasted my code. due to net connectivity its was late posted.. sorry for that..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy In case you're wondering *why* your code didn't work, it's because for **every footnote** you reset the `link` value by setting it to the single `footnote` value.

Comment: @h2ooooooo ya thankx i got id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array['link'] = array_merge(array($array['link']), $array['footnote']);
unset($array['footnote']);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Tempted to say +1 for doing it in the 2 lines of code, -1 for spoonfeeding an answer when OP doesn't show any evidence of having tried anything himself... eventually decided simply to upvote

Comment: @MarkBaker I have pasted my code. due to net connectivity its was late posted.. sorry for that..

Comment: @Puzzled Boy - well Pé's answer gives you a much cleaner and more efficient method

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as this:

```
$array['footnote'][] = $array['link'];
$array['link'] = $array['footnote'];
unset($array['footnote']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
  if ($key == 'link') {
    $array[$key] = $array['footnote'];
    $array[$key][] = $value;  
    unset($array['footnote']);
    continue;
  }
}
```